# Clearing the screen in C++ using other compilers

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Hello I'm interested in learning a way to clear the screen. I'm using C++ but it seem that some possible code to use are only known to work with Windows compilers. I'm using Ubuntu with  a "g++ compiler".

code i have research in order to use and  have tried...

---This don't work with g++ compiler

```
system("cls"); error: sh: 1: cls: not found
system("clrscr"); sh: 1: clrscr: not found
```

I stumble upon this code that it works, i know it prints lot's of lines ...

```
cout << string(50, '\n');
```

any cleaner methods that I could possibly use ?

Answer (score 4):

The Unix command for clearing the terminal is `clear`.

Alternatively, send the terminal codes for doing same (this varies by terminal, but this sequence works for most):

```
cout << "\033[H\033[2J";
```

(I got the sequence by simply running `clear | less` on my system. Try it and see if you get the same result.)

Comment: i know that but I'm not writing a Unix Shell script 
---thanks

Comment: Um, when you use `system("cls")`, that _is_ running a shell. So, just use `system("clear")`. (I was rather hoping I didn't have to spell it out quite so explicitly :-()

Comment: would _system("clear")_ work for example in Windows also ? it worked in Linux thanks for the help... in advance.

Comment: Does this code works for Windows the one you provide above...
`cout << "\033[H\033[2J";`
It worked on Linux but was wondering if it worked for windows...

Comment: @Cris: No, it won't work on Windows. There's really no good cross-platform way to clear the terminal. You can use an `#ifdef` to distinguish Windows from *nix.

Comment: A cross-platform cheat is printing a bunch of empty lines (That is no clear).